# How to add trigger dynamically to controls that are created dynamically

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, triggers, updatepanel

I have created a bunch of html element programatically in asp.net webforms and I have an `UpdatePanel` on my aspx page. Now I want to add triggers for every element's click event that are created.

Here is my code

```
string content = "";
int i = 1000;

string btnRight = "";
string btnLeft = "";

GroupsRepository gr = new GroupsRepository();

List<Group> groups = new List<Group>();
groups = gr.LoadListAllGroups();

foreach (Group gp in groups)
{
    btnLeft = "<button class='btnLeftService'  runat='server' value='مقالات' />";
    btnRight = "<button class='btnRightService' id='" + gp.GroupID.ToString() + "' runat='server' onserverclick='subGroups_ServerClick' value='زیر گروه ها' />";
    content += "<div  class='item'>";
    content += "<div class='row m0 service '><div class='row m0 innerRow item'><div><i class='fa fa-laptop'></i><div class='serviceName'>" + gp.Title + "</div></div><div class='item-overlay left'><ul><li class='liLeft'>" + btnLeft + "</li><li class='liRight'>" + btnRight + "</li></ul></div></div></div>";
    i++;
}

ourServises.InnerHtml = content;

GroupsRepository gr = new GroupsRepository();

List<Group> groups = new List<Group>();
groups = gr.LoadListAllGroups();

foreach (Group gp in groups)
{
     AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
     trigger.ControlID = gp.GroupID.ToString();
     trigger.EventName = "Click";
     updatepanel2.Triggers.Add(trigger);
}
```

but at runtime,  I get this error:

> A control with ID '1' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'updatepanel2'.

What should I do?

Comment: is UpdatePanel also created dynamically?

Comment: @Asif.Ali no ,its static

Comment: You are not creating dynamic controls but html elements as a string. Adding `runat=server` to them as a string does not make a asp:control. You need to create actual controls and add them to a PlacerHolder.

Comment: I'm using html elements as string becuase there is lots of elements @VDWWD

Comment: Yes, but then you're never be able to assign a trigger.